# Delay running next line of code when using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want my code to wait 500 milliseconds before performing the next step.

I've used `setTimeout` but it doesn't work.

```js
updateDisplay = arr => {
  setTimeout(function () {
    this.setState({ sortArray: arr });
  }, 500);
};
```

Comment: Chance `function() {` to an arrow function `() => {` so that you use the `this` in the surrounding scope, and not the one that gets bounded to your function expression

Comment: Yes it does thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some simple incorrect syntax.

```js
updateDisplay = (arr) => {
  setTimeout(() => this.setState({ sortArray: arr }), 500);
};
```